# How to call an async function in a vector of std::future?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to pass the function `countVocals()` (which returns an integer) to a vector of `future` but I'm getting this issue:

```
'No matching function for call to async:'
candidate template ignored
```

How can I fix it?

I have tried both with the following syntax and with a lambda expression but I get the same issue

```
int countVocals(std::string const &fileName, int &found);
std::vector<int> vocals(argc-1, 0);
std::vector<std::future<int>> futures(argc-1);

for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    futures.push_back(std::async(countVocals, std::string(argv[i]), vocals.at(i-1)));
```

Comment: prototype of `countVocals`?

Comment: int countVocals(std::string const &fileName, int &found)

Answer (score 1):

`countVocals` expects a reference, so you need to explicitly pass a reference to `st::async`:

```
futures.push_back(std::async(countVocals, std::string("Bla"), std::ref(vocals.at(i))));
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```